# What are the natural ways to increase the blood pressure?

Tags: blood-pressure

My BP is 87 by 69 as I post this.

Is there something which I can consume daily in a certain amount to keep my blood pressure normal?

Or are there any other ways to increase the blood pressure naturally?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're saying that you have a low blood pressure and you're seeking to reestablish a phisiological value I would answer you that low blood pressure it's not a disease unless it's really too low, but this is something you should **clarify with your doctor**. Also, if there's a disease, you should first cure the causes instead of lookin for functional foods to use as they were pills (="I have X, I eat Y for this"). Again this is something to check with doctors.

If you're asking which foods have the power to increase blood pressure, I would answer: **salt**<sup>[1](http://hyper.ahajournals.org/content/27/3/481.short)</sup>, **liquorice**<sup>[2](http://europepmc.org/abstract/med/11494093)</sup>. Then I suggest you to [check a link](http://www.webmd.com/heart/understanding-low-blood-pressure-treatment) that might be useful.

Answer (score -3):

**Increase your caffeine intake**-
Caffeine can cause a short, but dramatic increase in your blood pressure, even if you don't have high blood pressure

[Reference article](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/high-blood-pressure/expert-answers/blood-pressure/faq-20058543)

Comment: And what happens when the effects of caffeine dwindle? How much caffeine should one take to maintain the desired blood pressure and what are the risks associated with this? I had to downvote such an off-hand answer :-(.